# GitLab CI starts unexpected docker:dind version

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

**I wanted to use docker:dind service in GitLab CI to build docker image, but the runner kept starting the wrong dind version (19.03.8-dind) and show the error message below.**

`Error response from daemon: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp: no such file or directory`

Recently, I updated Docker version from 18.06.1 to 19.03.12 in the host server running my gitlab-runner and occurred the problem.

NOTE: It worked all good before this upgrade. I tried to downgrade the Docker version to 18.06.1, no luck this time. The GitLab Runner uses this Docker as the executor.

I previously used 19.03.8-dind to serve as the docker daemon. I used **docker system prune** to remove every image in the host, but the error still existed.

I follow the [GitLab Docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#tls-disabled) to configure the .gitlab-ci.yml.

Here is the .gitlab-ci.yml file

```
stages:
  - build

docker build:
  stage: build
  # this is my customized docker image with golang:1.14 and docker:19.03.0
  image: go-docker:1.14-19.03.0 
  services:
    - name: docker:19.03.0-dind
  variables:
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
  tags:
    - linux
  before_script:
    - docker version
  script:
    - docker build ......
```

and **docker version** output is

```
 $ docker version
 Client: Docker Engine - Community
  Version:           19.03.0
  API version:       1.40
  Go version:        go1.12.5
  Git commit:        aeac9490dc
  Built:             Wed Jul 17 18:11:50 2019
  OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
  Experimental:      false
 Server: Docker Engine - Community
  Engine:
   Version:          19.03.8
   API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
   Go version:       go1.12.17
   Git commit:       afacb8b7f0
   Built:            Wed Mar 11 01:30:32 2020
   OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
   Experimental:     false
  containerd:
   Version:          v1.2.13
   GitCommit:        7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429
```

The GitLab version is 12.10.3 and GitLab-runner is 12.10.2.

What should I do to fix the problem while still using the dind approach?

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble installing Gitlab Runner and using the `docker:dind` service on a cheapie $5 VM in Amazon Lightsail.

This has become urgent for me this month since Gitlab has [reduced runner minute quotas](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/09/01/ci-minutes-update-free-users/) on the FREE plan from 2000 minutes to 400.

After trying the installation a few times I worked out the problem was that Docker was not running in priviledged mode.

The [full install script](https://gist.github.com/sdesalas/58fbfea60136e9493069f3a873936313) is as follows, you can run this on a new VM, it includes explanation links:

```sh
# 1. INSTALL GITLAB RUNNER 
# @see https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-repository.html

curl -L https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/runner/gitlab-runner/script.deb.sh | sudo bash
export GITLAB_RUNNER_DISABLE_SKEL=true; sudo -E apt-get install gitlab-runner

# 2. INSTALL DOCKER
# @see https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/

sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg-agent software-properties-common
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu  $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io

# 3. REGISTER RUNNER WITH GITLAB.COM
# @see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#tls-enabled

sudo gitlab-runner register -n \
  --url https://gitlab.com/ \
  --registration-token $REGISTRATION_TOKEN \
  --executor docker \
  --description "My Docker Runner" \
  --docker-image "docker:19.03.12" \
  --docker-privileged \
  --docker-volumes "/certs/client"
```

After this I was able to run the `docker:dind` service without problems, I didnt even need to specify any of the special images like `docker:19.03.12-dind`:

```yaml
image: docker

services:
  - docker:dind

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker info

    ... your code needing docker here ...
```